# I want to use loop in flutter so that this code repeats multiple time

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use loop in Flutter so that whenever i call this class it's code get executed multiple times.
please solve any error in this code or please give me another method that gives same output

```
class tryy extends StateLessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext Context){
       var i = 1;
       while(i<=5){
          i = i+1;
          return Text("hey")
         }
        }
       }
```

Comment: Why do you have a while loop with a return in it? This has nothing to do with dart... How can a loop run if you have a return statement inside of it? It will return on the first loop.

Comment: @D. Go. are you trying to create a list view or something?

Comment: if you're trying to create a list view, check this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a whole class for that, simply you can create a method that retruns a list of widgets and you can use that result in Row or Column ...

```
List<Widget> repeatWiget(Widget widget, int times){
   List<Widget> res = List();
       for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
           res.add(widget);
       }
   return res;
}
```

and you can use that for example like this:

```
Column(children:repeatWiget(Text("repeat me 5 times"), 5)
```

Comment: and what if I want to return a variable with it that increases its count everytime the widget is executed

Comment: @D.Go. you should look into static variables in classes or state variables in a stateful widget.